Match the ttyUSB device nodes with the corresponding ALSA hw devices

Match the ttyUSB device nodes with the corresponding ALSA hw devices.
When I connect a USB speaker/mic, a ttyUSB0 node is created, and a sound-related hw:1,0 PCM device appears. We understand that ttyUSB0 corresponds to hw:1,0. However, if I connect two USB speakers/mics or other earphone , ttyUSB0 and ttyUSB1 are created, and two devices, hw:1,0 and hw:1,1, appear. In this case, how can I identify which ttyUSB node created which hw device at runtime?
How can we achieve this from a programming perspective?
